# Resizing QOpenGLTexture preserving properties

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am trying to resize QOpenGLTextures preserving the specified properties. I am aware of the fact that immutable storage is used, when possible. So i have to destroy and recreate the texture. But it seems the QOpenGLTexture looses its properties after destroy.

```
void resizeTexture(std::shared_ptr<QOpenGLTexture> texture, const Qsize &size){
    texture->destroy();
    texture->setSize(size.width(),size.height());
    texture->create();
    texture->allocateStorage();
}
```

Executing the `texture->allocateStorage();` statement fires up the QOpenGLDebugLogger printing the following:
`Warning: GL_INVALID_ENUM in glTexStorage2D(internalformat = GL_FALSE)`

So it seems to me that the previously setted properties like the texture target are lost after destroying the texture. So in my optinion they should be preserved for possible recreation of the texture.

Is there maybe another method to create a second QOpenGLTexture with identical properties except the size?

I filed therefore a bug report in the Qt bugtracker, but it seemed the devs are not able to take a look at it.
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-46614

So maybe someone here has a hint for me, what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Qt and OpenGL quite a lot.But I have never used Qt GL wrapper classes and I also do not recommend using those because this way you rely upon what is going on under the hood inside Qt SDK. Also because some API design flaws pointed out to in [this discussion](http://www.kdab.com/opengl-in-qt-5-1-part-1/) and also [here](http://www.kdab.com/opengl-in-qt-5-1-part-2/). But regarding your problem. Seems like Qt does it correct way (another reason why to use GL API directly),as prescribed by OpenGL standard. That's, if the texture handle is destroyed or re-initializes, which must be done if you need to resize, then all the texture objects props are invalidated.That's the way it should work. Btw,if you want to keep texture sampler properties you can use [OpenGL sampler objects](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_Object).And yeah, I have no idea how to use those with Qt GL wrapper API.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I reworked my design to be able to recreate the textures with all properties when a resize event occurs.

Comment: There's one benefit of Qt's OpenGL wrapper classes: if your code fits into OpenGL ES 2 straitjacket, it can run on DirectX via a translation layer (ANGLE) bundled with Qt. Qt already handles the dynamic selection of ANGLE vs. native GL, and you can further override such choice at runtime. Sometimes it's helpful.

Comment: @KubaOber  Agree,but I am saying it from the point of OpenGL developer :)

Comment: Also, if you happen not to use Angle, then the wrapper classes do literally nothing. The use of their methods has the "overhead" of a virtual method call. You simply are using function pointers.